# xampp MySQL Ignore - how to catch errors in PHP file

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in using transaction. My previous problem is about multiple inserts that should abort if one encounters an error and transaction with ignore solves it. My new problem is that I have to know if the insert is successful and if not should display the error.

```
PROFILE table
+--+----+---------+
|ID|NAME|BAL_LIMIT|
+--+----+---------+

NUMBER table
+--+----------+------+
|ID|PROFILE_ID|NUMBER|
+--+----------+------+
```

--TRANSACTION STATEMENT--

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `PROFILE` (`ID`, `NAME`, `BAL_LIMIT`) VALUES(NULL, "Name", 0);
INSERT INTO `NUMBER` (`PROFILE_ID`, `NUMBER`) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID() , "09123456789");
COMMIT;
```

--ERROR TO BE HANDLED--

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '09123456789' for key 'NUMBER_UNIQUE'
```

--PHP file contains--

```
    $vname = $_POST["iname"];
    $vbalancelimit = $_POST["ibalancelimit"];
    $vnumber = $_POST["inumber"];

$transaction = "START TRANSACTION;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `PROFILE` (`ID`, `NAME`, `BAL_LIMIT`) VALUES(NULL, \"$vname\", $vbalancelimit);
INSERT INTO `NUMBER` (`ID`, `PROFILE_ID`, `NUMBER`) VALUES(NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), \"$vnumber\");
COMMIT;";

$execute_transaction = mysqli_multi_query($con,$transaction) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($connection));

if (!$execute_transaction) {
            echo mysqli_error($connection);
} else {    echo "success"; }
```

**The PHP file always shows success though having #1062 error and the inserts are ignored.**

Comment: How are you setting the `$transaction` variable?

Comment: Show all the relevant code, or all you will get are guesses

Comment: Where you ever going to issue that query to the database for execution? I dont know where that error is coming from but it is not from the creation of a text string!!!!

Comment: When I'm using the transaction statement at xampp's UI, it displays the error. The only time the PHP file showed the error is when I removed the START TRANSACTION. I don't have any idea why it shows success even it has an error :(

Comment: you're not even executing the `$transaction` query. Come on...

Answer (score 0):

Multi-queried transaction statement problem solved.

Final PHP file:

```
<?php 
            $vname = $_POST["iname"];
            $vbalancelimit = $_POST["ibalancelimit"];
            $vnumber = $_POST["inumber"];

            $transaction = "
                START TRANSACTION;
                INSERT IGNORE INTO `PROFILE` (`ID`, `NAME`, `BAL_LIMIT`) VALUES(NULL, \"$vname\", $vbalancelimit);
                INSERT INTO `NUMBER` (`ID`, `PROFILE_ID`, `NUMBER`) VALUES(NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), \"$vnumber\");
                COMMIT;";

            $aff_rows = 0;

            if(mysqli_multi_query($con,$transaction)){
                do{$aff_rows+=mysqli_affected_rows($con);
                }while(mysqli_more_results($con) && mysqli_next_result($con));
            }if($aff_rows==2){//SUCCESS
                echo "<script>swal(\"$vname\", \"New number: $vnumber\", \"success\");</script>";
            }if($aff_rows==1){//WRONG NUMBER CORRECT NAME
                echo "<script>swal(\"Duplicate entry of $vnumber\", \"Failed to add for: $vname\", \"error\");</script>";
            }if($aff_rows==0){//WRONG NAME CORRECT/WRONG NUMBER
                echo "<script>swal(\"Duplicate entry of $vname\", \"Failed to add number: $vnumber\", \"error\");</script>";}
?>
```